# New multisite redirects to main site

Tags: multisite

I have created a new multisite and for some reason certain links redirect to the main site. For example if you go to http://team-isagenix.isagenixhealth.net and click on the October 2014 link under Archives. It will then redirect you to the main site (isagenixhealth.net) and I do not want this to happen. Do I need to make further changes in the htaccess file? Here is the code I have there right now: (Also please not I have other multisites on this account that work fine)

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/$      
 http://www.isagenixhealth.net/$4
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.isagenixhealth.net/$3

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.isagenixhealth\.net [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) http://mx.isagenixhealth.net/$1 [L,R=301]


 # uploaded files
 RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And here is the multisite part of my wp-config

```
 define( 'MULTISITE', true );
 define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
 $base = '/';
 define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'isagenixhealth.net' );
 define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
 define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
 define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out if I commented out the following line in the htaccess, it resolved the problem.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.isagenixhealth.net/$3
```